# User roles not displaying

Tags: users, user-roles

Can anyone explain why I cannot see the role from the code below:

```
$userID = get_current_user_id();
$user = get_userdata(userID);
<?php echo $user->roles; ?>
```

but I can see all the other user data such as

```
<?php echo $user->ID; ?>
<?php echo $user->user_login; ?>
```

I'm following [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see any roles printed, because the `->roles` field is an `Array`, so you can't print it using `echo`. User `print_r` instead.

You also have an error in this line:

```
$user = get_userdata(userID);
```

There is no such thing like `userID` - it should be `$userID`.

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$user = get_userdata(userID);
```

To

```
$user = get_userdata(YOUR_USER_ID_VARIABLE);
```

And check using `print_r($user->roles);`